# Check string from cell for match with any string from range, return corresponding value from different range

Tags: microsoft-excel

Cell A1 contains a long text string. Cells B1:B6 contain various shorter text strings. Cells C1:C6 contain values.

I want to search the string in cell A1 for partial matches in *any* of the strings from range B1:B6, and for *all* such partial matches, return the corresponding value from range C1:C6.

`=FILTER(C1:C6,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,B1:B6)))` returns the appropriate value(s) when one or more strings in range B1:B6 matches the string in cell A1 *exactly*, but returns no value in the case of a partial match. `=FILTER(C1:C6,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1,"*"&B1:B6&"*")))` yields the same result.

Any tips on where to go from here would be appreciated.

Comment: Should be like this : `=FILTER(C1:C6,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&B1:B6&"*",A1)))`

Comment: Why it should be like the one I have suggested and not like yours because --> You are searching cells `B1:B6` shorter text strings within Cell `A1`, so here, the first arg of `SEARCH()` say, **find_text** (`B1:B6`), **within_text** (`A1`). returns the position of the character within the string, if returned then wrap within `ISNUMBER()` to return `TRUE` and wrap with `FILTER()` to return the `C1:C6` based on the **include**

Comment: Egad, you're right. I was so close, and yet so far. :)

Comment: You can post this as an answer as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct formula should be:

```
=FILTER(C1:C6,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&B1:B6&"*",A1)))
```

I simply had the "find text" argument and the "within text" argument reversed inside the search function.